Can I add the same content in the same language under 2 different subdomains?
A website has 2 subdomains with the same language. We usually add the same content for each subdomain and I checked that both versions get indexed as we use Hreflang. So, is that correct, or should we make a blog for the root domain that has this content and make a news blog for each subdomain that has different content?

I assume you are aiming these sites at two different countries?  If so, as long as hreflang is configured correctly, what you are doing sounds correct.

Yes, you can technically do this, but it's usually not recommended due to potential duplicate content issues. Search engines may view them as competing and lower the rankings of both subdomains. If you need to use the same content, it's better to think about canonical tags to point to the original version to help search engines understand which version to give preference to when indexing and ranking.

Based on my experience, duplicate internal content it will not affect as long as there is a canonical tag. The canonical tag it just a signal for google to tell them "Google I want you to rank Page A instead of Page B.
If there are in the same language, honestly I don't see why you need to create 2 subdomains. Maybe I'm missing something, that's not clear.
I hope this help!
